# How to retrieve details (i.e. tags, commits) of gitlab projects within groups

Tags: api, gitlab

I am unable to retrieve project details from the gitlab API using the group structure of organizing projects.

`curl -X GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/:GROUP_ID/projects/` provides a list of all projects.
Attempting to get the details of a specific project using 
`curl -X GET https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/:GROUP_ID/projects/:PROJECT_ID`
returns a 404 even when the project ID exists.

Any ideas how I can retrieve project details when these projects are nested within Gitlab groups?

I should be able to get project details such as commit_ids and tags when I attempt getting the project details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint you've given is not a valid endpoint. `/api/v4/groups/:group_id/projects` will give you a list of all projects within a given group. However, if you then want to get details about that project you will use a different endpoint.

The projects endpoint is `/api/v4/projects/:project_id`. You can learn more about this endpoint, the attributes you can send with your query, and the details it returns in the documentation at [GitLab Projects API - Get single project](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#get-single-project)